# Django many-to-one relationship: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django

I'm trying to add data to many-to-one relationship tables.

```
# models.py
class Exp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Analysis(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run)


# my_management_command.py
experiment = Exp(name='sss')
analysis = Analysis(run=experiment)
analysis.save()
```

It works fine in the admin page, but in my management command it fails upon attempt to save:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: webint_analysis.exp_id
```

Why is it complaining about the id and how to fix that?
Note that I deleted my db to ensure that this is NOT related to migration.

Comment: are you saving experiment before assigning it to analysis?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That was the problem. I thought it would automatically save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Exp` object does not have a database ID while you are trying to use it in the `Analysis` object creation. You should first save the first object then use it.

You can do the following

```
experiment = Exp(name='sss')
experiment.save()
analysis = Analysis(run=experiment)
analysis.save()
```

Or you can use the folllowing

```
experiment = Exp.objects.create(name="sss")
analysis = Analysis.objects.create(run=experiment)
```